# Npm prompt - custom validation and multiline message?

Tags: javascript, node.js, prompt

I'm working on a CLI program, based on nodejs and the npm package "prompt". 
Let say I want to have this prompt, putting the input in a variable `pet`:

```
Choose a pet:
(1) - Cat
(2) - Dog
(3) - Fish
(4) - Rabbit
(5) - Rat
: >
```

Basically I did the functionality, but I'm having the following problems:

1. If I use the `conform` function for custom validation - then my custom message - the multiline text - never appears. The name of the variable - `pet` - only appears. But I want to have validation, cause I want to make sure the user won't enter `333` for example.
2. If I remove the `conform` custom validation - I can have multiline text, but then something else happens: the blinking rectangle, where the entering happens, overlaps with the multiline text. And I can't make it `blink` after the last line of the multiline message.

(In the above example the blinking happens over the digit 5.)

Any idea how to resolve the two issues I have ? ... :)

================== EDIT: Added code samples ===================

This is how I generate the multiline text:

```
// generate the multiline text .. 
var petsMessage = 'Choose a pet: \n';
var pets = [...];
for(var i = 0, l = pets.length; i < l; i++) {
    petsMessage += ' (' + (i+1) + ') - ' + pets[i] + "\n";
}
```

This is how I generate the prompt with multiline text, but no validation:

```
// define the prompt stuff .. 
var promptInfo = {
    properties: {
        Pet: {
            message: petsMessage,
            required: true
        },
    }
};
```

And this is with validation, but multiline message not working:

```
// define the prompt stuff .. 
var promptInfo = [
    {
        name: 'Pet',
        message: petsMessage,
        required: true,
        conform: function(value) {

            value = parseInt(value);

            if(value > 0 && value < pets.length) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
];
```

Comment: can you post some of your code or any errors that might appear?

Comment: Added code samples :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the problem was that in the second snippet with the validation you assign the actual question in the message property, you should assign it in the description. The message property refers to error message. Try this please:

```
var petsMessage = 'Choose a pet: \n';
var pets = ["dog","cat","frog"];
for(var i = 0, l = pets.length; i < l; i++) {
    petsMessage += '\t (' + (i+1) + ') - ' + pets[i] + "\n";
}
var prompt = require('prompt');
var promptInfo = [
    {
        name: 'Pet',
        description: petsMessage,
        required: true,
        message: 'Options allowed:: 1'+'-'+pets.length,
        conform: function(value) {

            value = parseInt(value);

            return value > 0 && value <= pets.length

        }
    }
];

prompt.start();

prompt.get(promptInfo, function (err, result) {
    console.log('you Choose',result,'::::',pets[result.Pet-1])
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the solution from "alex-rokabills" is not perfect too :( ... It's definitely better, but I still see issues.

If I use small amount of items then it's OK:

[image: Maximum five items]

But if the number grows a little bit:

[image: Six or more items]

And for big prompts:

[image: Over 10 items]

Also - can I get rid of the "prompt:" at the begining ? ...